# Biblatex conditional elimination of fields

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Is there a way to add some code in the preamble of a LaTeX document so that certain fields of the .bib file are ignored conditionally? More precisely, I want the url field of my .bib entries to be ignored in the case the entry already has a DOI or a arXiv identifier.